# Порядок срабатывание функций в Unity. C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, события

Какая функция сработает раньше? OnDeselect или OnPointerDown?

Comment: Отладка не помогает? [Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, OnDeselect Сработает позже.

Ну, а чтобы точно убедиться в этом и больше не задавать подобных вопросов почитайте про "точки останов". Тогда вы сможете не только узнать, какой порядок выполнения, но и определенные данные глянуть.

1. Подключите Visual Studio к Unity, нажав кнопку Воспроизвести, клавиши COMMAND+ВВОД или клавишу F5.
2. Переключитесь в Unity и нажмите кнопку Воспроизвести, чтобы запустить игру в редакторе.
3. Когда игра запущена в редакторе Unity при подключении к Visual Studio, все проходимые точки останова будут приостанавливать выполнение игры и выводить соответствующую строку кода в Visual Studio.

Остановка отладки:
Нажмите кнопку Остановить в Visual Studio для Mac или клавиши SHIFT+COMMAND+ВВОД.
Windows: В Visual Studio нажмите кнопку Стоп или используйте сочетание клавиш SHIFT + F5.